# Why does .css border-radius not work with Xamarin xaml

Tags: css, xamarin

I have numerous buttons defined in my xaml.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <x:StyleSheetExtension Source="Default.css" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

...

```
<Button x:Name="btnSale" BackgroundColor="#0000AA" Text="Sale" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" StyleClass="HeaderButtons" />
<Button x:Name="btnReturnExchange" Clicked="BtnReturnExchange_OnClicked" BackgroundColor="#0000AA" Text="Return/Exchng" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" StyleClass="HeaderButtons" />
<Button x:Name="btnOrder" Clicked="btnOrder_Clicked" BackgroundColor="#0000AA" Text="Order" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" StyleClass="HeaderButtons" />
<Button x:Name="btnARPayment" BackgroundColor="#0000AA" Text="A/R Payment" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="BtnARPayment_OnClicked" StyleClass="HeaderButtons" />
<Button x:Name="btnCustActivity" BackgroundColor="#0000AA" Text="Cust. Activity" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" StyleClass="HeaderButtons" />
<Button x:Name="btnAdministrator" Clicked="BtnAdministrator_OnClicked" BackgroundColor="#AAAAAA" Text="Administrator" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" StyleClass="HeaderButtons" />
<Button x:Name="btnRoutines" BackgroundColor="#AAAAAA" Text="Routines" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" StyleClass="HeaderButtons" />
```

I also have a Default.css file:

```
button {
    border-radius: 5;
}

.HeaderButtons {

    border-width: 2;
    font-size: 16;
    font-style: bold;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

No matter where I put the `border-radius: 5;`It will not round the corners like `CornerRadius="5"` which goes in the xaml file. I can leave it here or move it into the `.HeaderButtons` section, it makes no difference as far as I can tell. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: BorderRadius is deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.borderradius?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: `BorderRadius` is obsolete as of 2.5.0. Please use `CornerRadius` instead.